# Not able to compile the program shows ".class expected"

Tags: java

```
import static java.lang.Math.pow;
public class Power2
{
    public static void sampleMethod(int y)
    {
        long r=0;
        for(int i=0;i<=y;i++)
        {
            r =long(Math.pow(2,i));
            System.out.println("2*"+i+"="+r);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: There's a huge difference between compile and run.

Comment: Specifically for the value 2, `r = (long)Math.pow(2,i)` should be `r = 1L << i`

Comment: Why are you importing `pow`, then qualifying with `Math.pow`?

Answer (score 5):

Casts require parenthesis

```
r = (long) Math.pow(2,i);
    ^    ^
```